# T-SQL - How to deal with SELECT If Error Logic

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a simple select statement below:

```
SELECT Code =   Cast([Code] as int)
FROM dbo.table
```

I get an error:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '?' to data type
>   int.

I want to write IFERROR or CASE statement that would would replace error with a number such as -9999

Comment: SQL Server was indeed correct: '?' is not an integer.

Comment: I know it was correct. I was not sure how to deal with it. Solution works fine. Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    Code = CASE 
               WHEN ISNUMERIC(Code) = 1 THEN Cast([Code] as int) 
               ELSE -9999 
    END
FROM 
    dbo.table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Code = Cast((case when [Code] = '?' then -9999 else [Code] end) as int)
FROM dbo.table
```